# How to make two NODE.js servers communicate each other over RabbitMQ?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, messagebroker, event-driven

I wanted to create two servers in Node.js and make full-duplex communication with each other over rabbitMQ. I am new to messagebrokers or event-driven development, I just want to make one server serve API to the front-end another one just a chat server? Is that even a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directly with a broker is a bad idea. Typically, a gateway is added between the clients and the broker as an abstract layer. In this case, it will be easier for you to change the broker (for example, from rabbit to kafka, etc.), and you do not need to copy the client <-> broker logic in different languages. As example I just add this link [reddwarf](https://github.com/YaroslavGaponov/reddwarf). Simple demo service is [service](https://github.com/YaroslavGaponov/reddwarf/blob/main/packages/demo-typescript/src/demo-service.ts) and client is [client](https://github.com/YaroslavGaponov/reddwarf/blob/main/packages/demo-typescript/src/demo-client.ts)

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav, your repo gave me a good understanding of the message broker.